# How to delete rows if consecutive (ONLY) duplicates presents in all columns in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, duplicates, unique

I have a large data frame with four columns having over 10k rows and most of the rows are repetitive. I just want to keep the unique rows and remove the rows that have consecutive repetitions in all four columns.

The first 10 rows of the dataframe is given below,

```
 ENTREZID  G1.SYMBOL    G2.SYMBOL    G3.SYMBOL   
   <chr>     <chr>        <chr>        <chr>       
 1 105378589 LOC105378589 LOC105378589 LOC105378589
 2 2563      GABRD        GABRD        GABRD       
 3 2563      GABRD        GABRD        GABRD       
 4 2563      GABRD        GABRD        GABRD             
 5 339448    C1orf174     C1orf174     NA 
 6 339448    C1orf174     C1orf174     C1orf174
 7 55966     AJAP1        AJAP1        AJAP1       
 8 10277     UBE4B        UBE4B        NA          
 9 2810      SFN          SFN          SFN         
10 339488    TFAP2E       NA           TFAP2E
```

The expected output would be,

```
 ENTREZID  G1.SYMBOL    G2.SYMBOL    G3.SYMBOL   
   <chr>     <chr>        <chr>        <chr>       
 1 105378589 LOC105378589 LOC105378589 LOC105378589
 2 2563      GABRD        GABRD        GABRD  
 5 339448    C1orf174     C1orf174     NA 
 6 339448    C1orf174     C1orf174     C1orf174       
 7 55966     AJAP1        AJAP1        AJAP1  
 8 10277     UBE4B        UBE4B        NA          
 9 2810      SFN          SFN          SFN         
10 339488    TFAP2E       NA           TFAP2E
```

Comment: `df2 <- df[!duplicated(df),]` would remove rows that were all dups across all cols

Comment: Debajyoti Kabiraj, if Mike's comment and the dupe-links don't resolve this fully for you, please [edit] your question to explain why it doesn't work, then you can @-ping me and we'll work through the issues. Thanks, and good luck!

Comment: `library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(ENTREZID,G1.SYMBOL,G2.SYMBOL,G3.SYMBOL) %>% 
summarise(count = n()) %>% 
select(-c(count)) `